# Possible to force popup dialog to refresh?

Tags: python, add-on

Is it possible to force a popup called with invoke_props_dialog to refresh ?

For exemple, if i have a check box and i want, when this check box is activated, to display some options, it's not working.

How oblige Blender to make a refresh ?